# False Warning in Editor for Missing bracket in PHP tag

Tags: php, html, editor, aptana

I'm editing an html file with embedded php code. The editor tells me, quite incorrectly, that there is a ">" missing at the end of the php tag. This question was asked without resolution back in December 2013. I thought I would post my own question to revisit this very annoying issue.

---

[image: Warning about php tag]

Update Nov. 2015:

Here's what I have on the Validators filter for HTML Sytnax. Somehow the regex isn't working. I still get " "<" missing '>' for end of tag. " It seems to me that the expression is written properly.

[image: HTML Validator Settings]

Comment: I spent the last year using Aptana, and it is quite behind the times concerning modern syntax changes. It won't hurt anything to be aware of its shortcomings and continue coding. Not a fixable item until Aptana updates their syntax awareness

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. What version of Aptana are you using? What editor are you using, and is your file extension .html? Perhaps you could include a complete script with this error?

Comment: Using Aptana 3 under Linux Mint. And yes, the file has a html extension that uses php snippets within.  
  
Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805  
Build: jenkins-studio3-rcp-master-302 (origin/master)  
Date: 08 August 2013, 18:06:10

Answer (score 0):

Not shure, but maybe inside header.php closes the tag.